# How to Kill Sleeping MySQL connection using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, shell, database-connection, percona

Here's a summary of what I have tried:

You can do this in a shell script but you won't be able to do this if your server is running with `--secure-file-priv` option enabled. And I don't want to disabled it.

Although, to be completely fair, --secure-file-priv allows you to export to a certain directory. You can do a

```
show global variables like '%secure%';
```

and you'll get the path where you are allowed to write MySQL result sets directly into a file.

**1. Shell Script requiring --secure-file-priv disabled**

```
mysql -e "select concat('KILL ',id,';') from information_schema.processlist where Command =    'Sleep' AND user = 'root' into outfile '/tmp/sleep_processes.txt'"
mysql -e "source /tmp/sleep_processes.txt;"
rm -rf /tmp/sleep_processes.txt
```

**2. Percona's pt-kill**

To kill sleeping connections using Percona's `pt-kill`

```
pt-kill --match-command Sleep --kill --victims all --interval 10
```

**3. Python Script with pandas**

A Python script to list all the queries to be killed in a Pandas frame. But how do I execute each command in a Pandas frame.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import pandas as pd
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'mydatabase');
with con:
 cur = con.cursor()
 cur.execute("select concat('kill ',id,';') sleeping_connections FROM information_schema.processlist isp WHERE Command = 'Sleep' and time > 60")
 rows = cur.fetchall()
 df = pd.DataFrame( [[ij for ij in i] for i in rows] )
 df.rename(columns={0: 'Sleeping Connections'}, inplace=True);
 print(df.head(10))
```

Comment: @jezrael - FYI.

Comment: Have you considered setting the `wait_timeout` in MySQL system variable?

Comment: @TanHongTat - Yes, but that is permanent. An application connecting to MySQL will have pooling issues if I set that to too low. However, this cron job was a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the temp file (and thus the secure-file-priv problem) by doing your own text processing. This makes shell scripting feasible without having to disable secure-file-priv.

```
IDS=$(mysql -Be 'show processlist' | awk '$5 ~ /Sleep/ {print $1}')
for i in $IDS; do
    mysql -Be "kill $i"
done
```

Or you can do it in a one-liner:

```
mysql -Be 'show processlist' | awk '$5 ~ /Sleep/ {print $1}'| xargs -n 1 -i%% mysql -Be "kill %%"
```

The "-B" invokes "batch mode", which eliminates the pretty boxing you usually get when you run mysql commands. With that, you can use simple text processing to kill everything.

Note that both of these make multiple connections to server as written (one to get processes, and one for each KILL). You could rewrite it to issue all the KILLs in one connection, if that matters in your environment.